# EF multiple contexts: read/write

Tags: .net, entity-framework

my task is to have a component that allows persistent data reads/writes utilizing Entity Framework. Keeping in mind the following:

- I do not care about 'written/updated' data should be immediately accessible for reading (or changes should be immediately available for reader);
- I would like to turn off entities tracking when reading for performance sake;
- Data reading and writing will run continuously;

So the question is:
is this a good idea to have two separate contexts, that will live as long as components lives. One context is for write/update (with periodically SaveChanges call), another one is for reading (with entities tracking off).

Will I potentially gain benefits or on the contrary have issues with this approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a good idea because you would be a duplication of your data model that would not be able to control.

Answer (score 0):

the recommended practice is to have shorter lived contexts, so they dont endup holding too many objects in memory and thus conflicting changes and complex relationships

this might help

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2008/03/02/more-about-how-to-fit-the-objectcontext-into-apps.aspx